# CoreBluetooth Advertising not starting

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth

I am trying to write a simple app that constantly broadcasts a 'beacon' even when the app is not active. I know that using **CoreLocation** will switch this off when the app is not in use so I was trying to build a solution using **Core Bluetooth**.
The trouble is that I can't get the app to start advertising.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    var centralManager:CBCentralManager = CBCentralManager()
    var peripheralManager:CBPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
    let uuid:CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "DCEF54A2-31EB-467F-AF8E-350FB641C97B")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        self.centralManager.delegate = self
        let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"my-peripheral", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: uuid]
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([uuid], options: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: NSError?) {
        print("started advertising")
        print(peripheral)
    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("peripheral discovered")
        print("peripheral: \(peripheral)")
        print("RSSI: \(RSSI)")
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("central state updated")
        print(central.description)
        if central.state == .PoweredOff {
            print("bluetooth is off")
        }
        if central.state == .PoweredOn {
            print("bluetooth is on")
            let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"my-peripheral", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: uuid]
            let service = CBMutableService(type: uuid, primary: true)
            self.peripheralManager.addService(service)
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
            centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        }
        if central.state == .Unsupported {
            print("bluetooth is unsupported on this device")
        }
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        print("peripheral state updated")
        print("\(peripheral.description)")
    }

}
```

I have installed this on two devices, the issue seems to be in the transmission of the advert since `peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising()` is never called.

Comment: You can't start advertising until you have verified the power on state in `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState`

Comment: I could not find the `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` delegate method. I am starting advertising in `centralManagerDidUpdateState`. This was also taking place in `viewDidLoad()` but I have since commented this out.

Comment: The `peripheralManagerDidUpdateState` method is in the code you have shown, it just has an empty implementation - you need to check for the power on state before advertising, but more importantly your `CBMutableService` instance needs to be stored in a property, not a local variable otherwise it will be released once `centralManagerDidUpdateState` exits; `CBPeripheralManager` does not retain the CBMutableService

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to immediate call `.startAdvertising()` right after `.addService()` call.

You must call `.startAdvertising()` ONLY after `func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?)` delegate method is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this init method the centralManagerDidUpdateState is going to work. You can set the CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey option if you would like to see the beacons continually.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

var centralManager:CBCentralManager!
var peripheralManager:CBPeripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager()
let uuid:CBUUID = CBUUID(string: "DCEF54A2-31EB-467F-AF8E-350FB641C97B")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"my-peripheral", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: uuid]
    peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
    centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([uuid], options: [ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: NSError?) {
    print("started advertising")
    print(peripheral)
}


func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print("peripheral discovered")
    print("peripheral: \(peripheral)")
    print("advertisement: \(advertisementData)")
    if let data = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceData"] {
        print("found advert data: \(data)")
    }
    print("RSSI: \(RSSI)")
}

func startAdvert(){
    let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"my-peripheral", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: uuid]
    peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
    print("peripheral disconnected")
    print("peripheral: \(peripheral)")
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("central state updated")
    print(central.description)
    if central.state == .PoweredOff {
        print("bluetooth is off")
    }
    if central.state == .PoweredOn {
        print("bluetooth is on")
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: [ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
        startAdvert()
    }
    if central.state == .Unsupported {
        print("bluetooth is unsupported on this device")
    }
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    print("peripheral state updated")
    print("\(peripheral.description)")
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks Gyorgy. I am avoiding the use of CoreLocation because I need to be able to transmit when the app is not active (all the time). Also I don't want to detect region changes, just a list of the phones in range.

Comment: Gyorgy, your suggestion is the same as the OP.

Comment: Sorry to have to keep coming back to you but even with the changes I still can't broadcast in a manner that can be detected. My current View Controller links like this: `https://gist.github.com/marktyers/fa96e0a6f81eee4cf822`, I am running this on two different iPhones but one can't see the other.

Comment: I will try to show you how can you see the other device but I have to say you something. You can't write application in IOS what listening in the background forever because the IOS will close your background task after approximately five minutes. This is defense in the IOS so your app can't drain the battery in the background.

Comment: There is a new version of the example code. I haven't got two phone so I can't test for you.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it neither transmits nor detects.

Answer (score 0):

The CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey value passed to startAdvertising should be an array of CBUUID objects but you are passing a single CBUUID

```
let advertisingData = [CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:"my-peripheral", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [uuid]]
```